# FindFragmentById not returning null

Tags: android, fragment

I have the following code:

//Compruebo si tengo los dos fragmentos

```
FichaAlumnoFragment frag=(FichaAlumnoFragment)getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.details_students_frag);
        if (frag!=null) {
            Log.i(this.getClass().getSimpleName(),"Tengo dos fragmentos");
            mDualFragments=true;
        }
```

If I'm in portrait mode it returns null. If I change to landscape (Ctrl+11 in the emulator) frag has a value and the layout is rendered correctly but If I change again to portrait it's supposed to have a null value but returns some value and the app crashes.

Layout are different for both orientations

Think I misunderstood fragment lifecylce. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue. You still have to check for null, but then also check with the method **isInLayout()**, for instance:

```
if (null == getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_example) || !getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.fragment_example).isInLayout()) {
    // Fragment has not been created or it is not visible
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well i found the solution..al least one that works for me...

Once I have loaded a fragment in a layout (landscape) although I change orientation (a layout with only one fragment) findFragmentById is always returning true althoug i change to portrait once more. If I also check isInLayout it works right.

Found it at:

http://android10.org/index.php/articlesuserinterface/309-learn-how-to-implement-fragments-in-android